# Proof $\mathcal{C}^1(-1,1)$ is not a closed subspace of Sobolev space $H_0^1 \left[-1,1\right]$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Give a sequence of functions $\varphi_n\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(-1,1)$, Cauchy with respect to the Sobolev space $H^1_0$ norm

$$\| \varphi\|_1=\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 (\varphi')^2+\int_{-1}^1 \varphi^2}$$

which does not converge to a function in $\mathcal{C}^1\left[-1,1\right]$.

I was told an useful approach would be taking a wedge shaped function $f$ in $\mathcal{C^0}(-1,1)$ (i.e. continuous but not differentiable) and considering the convolution $$\psi_n \ast f$$
where $\psi_n$ is a regularizing sequence of functions. It then follows that
$$\|(\psi_n\ast f) -f\|_2$$

I am stumped as to what follows, or what I should do next. The weak derivatives do not have the regularity conditions required to apply the above argument to them.

I am new to this subject; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does $H_0^1([-1;1])$ contain $|x|^{1/2+\epsilon}$ ? (or $x^{1/2+\epsilon}$ or $x^{1/2+\epsilon}\! _{x \le 0}$). otherwise, yes your proof is quite general, working for my examples and also for yours $|x|$ which is not $C^1$ and has a $L^2([0;1])$ (weak) derivative.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate further on your comment?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\|\psi_{n}\star f-f\|_{L^2}\rightarrow 0$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ for any $f \in L^2$. If you start with the wedge $f$ as described, then $\|\psi_{n}\star f - f\|\rightarrow 0$ and
$$
       \|(\psi_{n}\star f)'-f'\|=\|\psi_{n}'\star f-f'\|=\|\psi_{n}\star f'-f'\|\rightarrow 0.
$$
This is because, even though $f$ has only a piecewise continuous derivative,
\begin{align}
     \frac{d}{dx}\int \psi_{n}(x-y)f(y)dy & =\int \psi_{n}'(x-y)f(y)dy \\
    & = -\int \frac{d}{dy}\psi_{n}(x-y)f(y)dy \\
    & = \int \psi_{n}(x-y)f'(y)dy.
\end{align}
Therefore $\psi_{n}\star f \rightarrow f$ in $H^1$.

Comment: The problem is precisely the piecewise continuous derivative. I am not sure I can use the convergence theorem for the convolution because it requires the function to be continuous.

Comment: @alonso s : equivalently, it requires the function to be integrable, and with you example $|x|$ both the function and its derivative are.

Comment: But the derivative is only piecewise continuous

Comment: @aloson s : you have to learn how to prove that the discontinuity point (of the derivative) counts for nothing (in $L^2$), it is the interesting part of your problem.

Comment: @aloson : You can easily show that $\psi_n\star f'\rightarrow f'$ at points of continuity of $f'$, and that the function $\psi_n\star f'$ remains bounded by the same bound for $f'$. That's enough to use the bounded convergence theorem in the above to show that $\|\psi_{n}\star f'-f'\|_{L^2}\rightarrow 0$.